# Changing I2C Address on Garmin LidarLite, resets on reboot

Tags: i2c

I am trying to change the I2C address of multiple Garmin LidarLite-V3. I am able to change them one at a time using the LidarLite C++ library using the setI2Caddr function, and can see the updated I2C address using i2cdetect. The problem is that when the LidarLite loses power and turns back on, the address is reset to the default 0x62. This means when I have multiple LidarLite connected in parallel, they all default to the same I2C address and I am unable to individually change the addresses using the setI2Caddr function. How can I change the I2C address so that it persists through a power cycle, or alternatively change the addresses when multiple LidarLite are connected in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/LIDAR_Lite_v3_Operation_Manual_and_Technical_Specifications.pdf) of the Garmin Lidar Lite tells you about this. From page 5 under "Configurable I2C Address":

> This can be used to run multiple devices on a single bus, by enabling one,
> changing its address, then enabling the next device and repeating the
> process.
>
> The I2C address will be restored to default after a power cycle

So you cannot change the fact, that the I2C addresses will be reset to the default value on power cycle. But on startup you can give each sensor its own address. For that you need to wire the Power Enable pins to digital pins on the Arduino. When the digital pin is HIGH, the sensor is deactivated. So you start with all the Power Enable pins on HIGH. Then you set the first Power Enable pin to LOW, set the sensors I2C address via the corresponding I2C command and then proceed to the next sensor. When finished every sensor has its corresponding address and you don't get any collisions on the bus, since you always have only one sensor with the default address enabled at any time.